# Query to subtract Now()-[Table].[Field]

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to run a query that subtracts a certain amount of days from today and filters on that result. I'm working in Access 2007

This works but I need to read the 50 from a table named `SetupExp.qryFilter`

```
SELECT CustItemExp.LocationKey, CustItemExp.MarketBasket, CustItemExp.SaleDate
FROM CustItemExp
WHERE Now() -50;
```

I've tried `WHERE Now() -[SetupExp].[qryFilter]`
No luck, it just prompts for a value.

I want to put the 50 in a table/field so the query can read it without user input.

Comment: If you want to always subtract 50, why do you need user input or reference another table field? How can that WHERE clause work - there is no field specified to apply filter to.

Comment: The value 50 will be changed over time. The setupexp table can be accessed with a form and changed when needed. I do not want user input when this query is run. In fact I want this query to run periodically all by itself

Comment: Do a cross join between your main table and your parameter table. Once the table is referenced you should be able to  use it. Or reference the 50 via a sub query such as `where now()-(select qryfilter from setupexp)`

Comment: where now()-(select qryfilter from setupexp) did not work, It returns all the records Not sure how to do a cross join

Comment: So if you don't want user input, does that mean setupexp has only 1 record? Google 'query cross join' also called a Cartesian query. Every record in each table associates with every record of other table. The result is a non-editable dataset. Could probably use DLookup() to pull value from setupexp.

Comment: Correct, setupexp has only 1 record

Comment: In addition, you should be using Date(), not Now()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you need to show records with `SaleDate` within the last 50 days from now and be able to store this number of days in SetupExp table. If so, you can use query like this:

```
SELECT CustItemExp.LocationKey, CustItemExp.MarketBasket, CustItemExp.SaleDate
FROM CustItemExp, SetupExp
WHERE CustItemExp.SaleDate > Now()-[qryFilter];
```

If you need editable query, as suggested in comments, use DLookup:

```
SELECT CustItemExp.LocationKey, CustItemExp.MarketBasket, CustItemExp.SaleDate
FROM CustItemExp
WHERE CustItemExp.SaleDate > Now()-DLookUp("qryfilter","SetupExp")
```

Comment: I tried both options and get a compile error with both

Comment: After some 'tweeking' on the db the second solution WORKS!! Thanks Sergey

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all `Now() - 50` is not the correct way to subtract 50 days from today. The correct way is `DateAdd('d', -50, Now())` or even better if you don't want to use time components and just use days `DateAdd('d', -50, Date())`.

You can use `DLookup` to look up a value from a table. If you are looking for a single fixed value (your table literally has a single record with that value) then you can use `DLookUp('qryfilter', 'SetupExp')`. If your table has multiple records and depending on how which record you want to use in relation to each `CustItemExp` you can either `JOIN` `CustItemExp` and `qryfilter` as part of your SQL statement or use the optional 3rd parameter of `DLookup` which acts as a `WHERE` type filter.